# how do return the $state.current.name from ui-router statechange

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I would like to return the  `.state('name')` when I change location in angular.

From my `run()` it can return the `$state` object:

```
 .run(function($rootScope, Analytics, $location, $stateParams, $state) {
      console.log($state);
```

[image: working object]

**but when I try to get`$state.current` it is empty object**

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location, $stateParams, $state) {

      console.log($state.current);
```

[image: empty]

**config example:**

```
 .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, AnalyticsProvider) {  
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
              '': {
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
              },
              'navigation@home': {
                templateUrl: 'views/partials/navigation.html',
                controller: 'NavigationCtrl'
              },
              'weekly@home': {
                templateUrl: 'views/partials/weekly.html',
                controller: 'WeeklyCtrl'
              },
              'sidepanel@home': {
                templateUrl: 'views/partials/side-panel.html',
                controller: 'SidePanelCtrl'
              },
              'shoppanel@home': {
                templateUrl: 'views/partials/shop-panel.html',
                controller: 'ShopPanelCtrl'
              },
              'footer@home': {
                templateUrl: 'views/partials/footer.html',
                controller: 'FooterCtrl'
              }
            }
          })
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can listen for  '$stateChangeSuccess' and set state accrodingly. For example -

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
  function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    $state.current = toState;
  }
)
```

Comment: Can you please provide an explanation of why the code in the question didn't work?

Comment: It has been deprecated; you need to use the IHookRegistry now @danm07 http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/feature-1.0/interfaces/transition.ihookregistry.html#onstart

Comment: This snippet will show the name of each state when it loads on the page...

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
        alert($state.current.name);
      }
    );

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to Sandeep's solution, you can also do it this way:

```
angular.module('yourApp').run(['$rootScope', '$state',
    function ($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
    }
]);
```

Doing it this way, it only gets set once instead of on ***every*** stateChange.  Basically you just store a reference to $state somewhere - I chose $rootScope just to keep this example simple.

Now in my code I can easily reference it like:

```
<div ng-show="$state.includes('accounting.dashboard')"></div>
```

and

```
<div>Current State: {{$state.current.name}}</div>
```

I also generally store $stateParams as well so I have even more information about the state (but I left it out of this example).

Comment: What do you mean with: it only gets set once instead of on every stateChange?

Comment: Because `run()` is called only once by the framework after all angular modules have been loaded. Which makes it the perfect location to setup things like the shortcut object `$rootScope.$state = $state;` once and for all. On the other hand `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess') ...` is an event handler called every time the state is changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try.

```
.controller('yourApp', function($scope,$state) {
  $scope.state = $state;
```

Now you can log it in your console.

```
console.log($state);
```

It should return the current state you are in.

Or you can call the scope in your html view like this.

```
{{state.current.name}}
```

It will also return de state you are in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to console your state in the controller then you should console like that:

```
console.log($state.current.name);
```

And if you want to console it in views then:

In controller :

```
$scope.state = $state.current.name;
```

In Template: print like that

```
{{state}}
```